# How to open safari inside an app IPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to open Safari inside an app in Iphone.
like there is a NavigationController & its view has safari in it.
how can i do this??
Any help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot open Safari "inside" of your application, but you can use the UIWebView control to display web content:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html